# Return only one row of a select that would return a set of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have a table like:

```
create table myTab(
  id integer primary key,
  is_available boolean not null default true
);
```

I need to do a query that returns only the first encountered row that has `is_available` set to false.

Comment: Filter by is_available, order by id if that indicates the first entry and then take the first element only.

Comment: Too basic. Just read [the manual about `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like

```
select *
from myTab
where not is_available
order by id asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS Postgres has a proper `boolean` type. Use `is_available = FALSE` or `NOT is_available` instead.

Comment: thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, it's obvious then PostgreSQL is not my most exp. DB :) But I like it very much

Answer (score 1):

Try out this ..

```
select id,is_available from myTab
where is_available = false
order by id asc
limit 1
```

If you want row from last inserted then go with this ..

```
    select id,is_available from myTab
    where is_available = false
    order by id desc
    limit 1
```

Comment: in my case, ordering by id isn't a bad solution, because i the id field involved in my query are a subset of all id contained in table (i have also another clause on WHERE)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `NOT EXISTS` to find the *first* tuple, in most cases this is the fastest solution, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTab mt
WHERE mt.is_available = False
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM myTab nx
    WHERE nx.is_available = False
    AND nx.id < mt.id
    );
```